# Rails: Load image from CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, less, asset-pipeline

In my view I can load a image with this line of code: `<div id="bglion"><%= image_tag("BG-LION6.png")%></div>` (this works), but instead I want to load the image from the CSS file.

After reading arround, I have tried this:

```
#bglion {src: background:url('BG-LION6.png');}
#bglion {src: asset-url('BG-LION6.png');}
#bglion {src: asset-url('BG-LION6.png', image);}
```

...but the picture won't load on the page.
How can I make it work?

(The image is in /assets/images)

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? Is your image in the `public` directory or the `assets` directory? Also is this CSS in a CSS file in your `assets` directory?

Comment: Im using Rails 3.2 and the image is in /assets/images

Comment: Well if your image is at `/assets/images/BG-LION6.png` and your CSS is in a stylesheet located in `/assets/stylesheets/` then it should be `#bglion {background:url('BG-LION6.png');}`.

Comment: My image is at that path and my stylesheet is in the `/assets/stylesheets/`. I have tried to use `#bglion {background:url('BG-LION6.png');}`, but it didn't work. I just cant understand what it could be...

Comment: Try this `#bglion {background:pink url('BG-LION6.png');}`. Let me know if you see pink on the screen where you expect to see the image.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need it to say `image-url('BG-LION6.png')`. If it just says `url('BG-LION6.png')` it's going to look in the root of your application after asset compilation, not the assets folder.

Comment: Er... One more glaring omission. My fault. Is your CSS file a `.css` or a `.css.erb` file?

Comment: @SandersKY: I tried your trick and it worked when I added height and width to it. Thanks! @Tracy Fu: both `url('BG-LION6.png')` and `image-url('BG-LION6.png')` worked :)

Comment: Awesome. Good luck with everything!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll have to do a couple of things. Your CSS should probably be something more along the lines of this:

```
#bglion { background: image-url('BG-LION6.PNG'); }
```

`background` is the CSS property you're actually trying to set. `src` is not a CSS property. `image-url` is a Rails path helper that points to your image assets folder. I believe if you just use `asset-url` it points to your entire assets folder and you would still have to specify that your image is in the images folder.

Secondly, if your `div` no longer contains an image within it, it will collapse to a width and height of 0 cause there's nothing to define its dimensions. You'll have to add more CSS to the wrapper div to define the dimensions of the image. So something like this:

```
#bglion { background: image-url('BG-LION6.PNG'); width: 100px; height: 100px; }
```

Comment: Could you tell us where your image is located and what your markup looks like?

Comment: You last example worked! (I must had done something wrong when I added it the first time. Sorry)

Comment: BTW: Is there a way to set width and height to match the picture dimension (so this is done automatic instead of me figuring out the exact size and type it in manually?)

Comment: I don't think you can without some trickery. Others might have a better idea. If you have the height and width stored or can retrieve them per item, you will have to add the dimensions as inline styles to the wrapper `div`s.

Answer (score 3):

Try to do this instead:

```
#bglion { background: url("/BG-LION6.png"); }
```

or

```
#bglion { background: url("/assets/BG-LION6.png"); }
```

Depending on which version of rails you're using and which folder you set your assets at.

When accessing assets, you should always make the path absolute instead of relative.

Comment: I have always made the path relative i.e. `#bglion { background: url("BG-LION6.png"); }` instead of absolute. What is the reasoning for always making it absolute?

Comment: It doesn't really matter in this case since stylesheets will always come from your assets folder by default, but if they changes places, they'll point relative to your stylesheets folder and will break. This is only if you change default configurations though and won't happen in 99% of cases.

Comment: @SandersKY Sorry my previous comment was incorrect so I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your css file to have a css.erb extension and then do something like this

```
#bglion {
background-image: url(<%=asset_path "BG-LION6.png"%>);
}
```